# Move to next field after input

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery.  I am trying to automatically move to the next field after a user inputs a correct format/pattern (regex value).

Here is what I have so far:

Form:

```
<form>
<label for="serial_number">Serial Number: </label>
<input type="text" id="serial_number" name="serial_number" placeholder="Serial Number" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" required autofocus />

<input type="text" id="second_entry" name="second_entry" placeholder="second_entry" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" required />

<input type="submit" value="Process" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.serial_number').keyup(function() {
var inputVal = $(this).val();
var characterReg = /^[0-9]\d{20}$/;
if(characterReg.test(inputVal)) {

$("serial_number").change(function() {
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
});

}
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apart from giving the code, please explain what part doesn't work.

Comment: Removed pattern from the HTML form.  And tried only using the jquery patern.  Jquery pattern works, but doesn't move to next field.

Comment: the .change() event is not fired until the input loses focus, look at using .keyup instead

Comment: you have `keyup` event first and then `change` event **inside** the `keyup` event...and you are expecting that to work...

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll look into .focus() function.

Comment: you're also missing the '#' from the selector on "serial_number".

Comment: may be easier if you post a jsfiddle. someone can then fix it for you and you can see what they did

Comment: You selector should be `$("#serial_number")`. Both of then are wrong in your code in different ways.

Comment: Why are you registering change event from inside the keyup event. it will end up regsitering multiple event as many number of keyups aheppned on the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is error in your selector.

```
$('.serial_number').keyup(function() {
```

to

```
$('#serial_number').keyup(function() {
```

**Update:** Try the below code:

```
$('#serial_number').keyup(function () {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var characterReg = /^[0-9]{5}$/;        
    if (characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
        var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
        inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

There is no need for `.change()`.  Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTrvP/)

Also you need to change your `regex`  to

> var characterReg = /^[0-9]{5}$/;

in the jQuery code because you have `maxlength="5"`

Comment: when I add a label to the second input it's not able to find the second field.  any ideas?

Comment: @Jeremy No using `$(this).closest('form').find(':input');` this looks for next `input` element not label.  If you miss this may be a chance.  I've added label and it is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xTrvP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. Have a look at the code...

http://jsfiddle.net/aVdex/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#serial_number').keyup(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var characterReg = /^\d{5}$/;
        if(characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
            $("#serial_number").next("input").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

For IDs you should use the `#` selector. For classes, use `.`. 
The `change` event is not fired until the input loses focus, so you need to do all your checking in the `keyup` event.
You can use the `next` function to get an element's immediate sibling.
`Focus` sets the user's focus to that element, and so puts the cursor in the next input here